# I'm trying to transfer over to a list from an array for my room search system in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, sorting

This is my function to search if the room is available or not and to make them not available anymore as this is apart of my check in system for a project of mine.

```
Function RoomAvailableFunc()
                Console.WriteLine("Rooms available:")
                For i = 0 To UBound(Rooms)
                    If roomFits(i) >= amountOfPeople Then
                        If roomAvailable(i) = True Then
                            Price = roomCosts(i) * daysStaying
                            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Rooms(i)))
                            Console.WriteLine("Maxinum in this room: " & roomFits(i))
                            Console.WriteLine("This room costs £" & Convert.ToString(roomCosts(i)) & " per night")
                            Console.WriteLine("Price for the visit: £" & Price)
                            roomsFound += 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i
                If roomsFound <= 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry we have not found any rooms for this criteria!")
                    Console.WriteLine("Please try again!")
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..")
                    Console.ReadKey()
                    Main()
                End If
                Console.WriteLine("Which room would you like to pick?")
                Console.Write("> ")
                roomNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())

                For i = 0 To UBound(Rooms)

                    If roomNumber = Rooms(i) Then
                        Price = roomCosts(i) * daysStaying
                        roomAvailable(i) = False
                    End If
                Next i
            End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is matching collections by index like this is not good. Much better to create a `Class` with the fields you need. Instead of separate arrays for `roomFits()`, `roomCosts()`, etc, you have one class like this:

```
Public Class Room
    Public Property ID As Integer 'System/Database ID
    Public Property RoomNumber As String
    Public Property MaxOccupants As Integer
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Property IsAvailable As Boolean
End Class
```

And then **ONE** list for instances of the that Room class:

```
Dim Rooms As New List(Of Room)()
```

When you are able to load the data for that list, we can start to look at the actual method:

```
Function SelectRoom(amountOfPeople As Integer, daysStaying As Integer) As Room
    Dim matches = Rooms.Where(Func(r) r.MaxOccupants >= amountOfPeople AndAlso r.IsAvailable).ToList()

    'Don't put the higher level program-flow here. Leave that for the calling method!
    If matches.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing

    Console.WriteLine("Rooms available:")
    For Each r As Room in matches
         Dim Price As Decimal = r.Price * daysStaying
         Console.WriteLine($"{r.RoomNumber}")
         Console.WriteLine($"Maximum in this room: {r.MaxOccupants}")
         Console.WriteLine($"This room costs £{r.Price} per night")
         Console.WriteLine($"Price for the visit: £{Price}")
         Console.WriteLine()
     Next r

     Console.WriteLine("Which room would you like to pick? ")
     Console.Write("> ")
     Dim selectedRoomNumber As String = Console.ReadLine()
     Return matches.FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.RoomNumber = selectedRoomNumber)          
 End Function
```

Now we have to change the calling code, too.

```
Dim selectedRoom As Room = Nothing
Dim triesRemaining As Integer = 3
While selectedRoom Is Nothing AndAlso triesRemaining > 0
    selectedRoom = SelectRoom(amountOfPeople, daysStaying)
    If selectedRoom Is Nothing Then
         triesRemaining -= 1

         Console.Write("No rooms matched this criteria. Try again (Y/N)?" )
         If Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper() = "N" Then
             triesRemaining = 0
         End If
    End If
End While
```